# Auto start app per Windows Virtual Desktop

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop

Using Windows 10 Virtual Desktop quite often but I started looking for a way to help automate which application would auto start on boot and have it load on the appropriate virtual desktop.

For example 2 desktops are being used... I would like Notepad on the first desktop and Wordpad on the second desktop when Windows loads so that I don't have to manually switch to that desktop and load the application.

Has anyone come across a way to accomplish this?

Comment: What you describe is not possible.  Any script that would run would only apply to the current desktop.

Comment: Best case scenario would be a script to move to that desktop and then start app from script then it seems. Was hoping to avoid that. Thanks for the quick response Ramhound. Cheers.

Comment: You might be able to write a script that does that, but, we are not a script writing service.

Comment: No worries, I am a script writing service ;)